# how to find all methods called in a method?

Tags: java, class, methods, bytecode

how to take the methods of other classes invoked in a specific method?

EXAMPLE

**method getItem1()**

```
public String getItem1() throws UnsupportedEncodingException{
    String a = "2";
    a.getBytes();
    a.getBytes("we");
    System.out.println(a);
    int t = Integer.parseInt(a);
    return a;
}
```

The methods called in `getItem1()` are:

1. `String.getBytes()`
2. `String.getBytes(String)`
3. `PrintStream.println(String)`
4. `Integer.parseInt(String)`

Comment: It is pretty difficult to figure out what you mean, please be a bit more specific. In what context? Do you want to parse Java source files? Do you want this information in runtime? What do you want this for?

Comment: It is really difficult to figure out the problem

Comment: It's tagged *bytecode*, so I guess he wants to analyze the .class file

Comment: Javassist might be of use: http://www.csg.ci.i.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I would do this with [javassist](http://www.csg.ci.i.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/).

So let's say you have the following class accessible in your classpath and want to find all methods invoked from **getItem1()**:

```
class MyClass {
  public String getItem1() throws UnsupportedEncodingException{
    String a = "2";
    a.getBytes();
    a.getBytes("we");
    System.out.println(a);
    int t = Integer.parseInt(a);
    return a;
  }
}
```

And you have this MyClass compiled.
Create another class that uses javassist api:

```
public class MethodFinder {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
    ClassPool cp = ClassPool.getDefault();
    CtClass ctClass = cp.get("MyClass");
    CtMethod method = ctClass.getDeclaredMethod("getItem1");
    method.instrument(
        new ExprEditor() {
            public void edit(MethodCall m)
                          throws CannotCompileException
            {
                System.out.println(m.getClassName() + "." + m.getMethodName() + " " + m.getSignature());
            }
        });
  }
}
```

the output of the MethodFinder run is:

```
java.lang.String.getBytes ()[B   
java.lang.String.getBytes (Ljava/lang/String;)[B   
java.io.PrintStream.println (Ljava/lang/String;)V   
java.lang.Integer.parseInt (Ljava/lang/String;)I
```

Comment: thank you very much, it's really what I'm looking for. since you seem to know very well _javassist_, you can apply the _methodfinder_ for methods of classes (such as java.lang.Date) present in the libraries?

Comment: yes you can, CtClass ctClass = cp.get("java.util.Date"); and you're good to go.

Comment: javassist also allows you to create a parsing method parameters?

For example, from (ILjava/lang/String;I) is obtained (int, java.lang.String, int)

Comment: I don't know if the detailed API exists, but 
m.getMethod().getLongName() will give you human-readable string, like: java.io.PrintStream.println(java.lang.String)